# How to determine control/data/address bus width

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am hoping you guys can help. I need to know how to calculate the control bus, address bus, and data bus width of a hypothetical CPU.

> A computer is word addressable with a 64 bit word size and 4GBytes of memory. The control unit can issue 184 different commands and there are 68 total interrupt or acknowledgement lines from devices back to the CPU. Given this information, how many bits wide are each of the address bus, control bus and data bus? 
>   I know the address bus width is 2^32/data bus width. But I have no idea how to calculate the control bus or data bus width.

I have searched my textbook and my course slides for hints and have come up empty. I am most interested in the methodology to determine this rather than the answer itself.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Linux with actual CPU: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18024/how-to-get-information-about-word-address-size-address-bus-size-data-bus-size